# Impossible to power off and lost of USB on dual boot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb, drivers, dualboot

I am facing a weird issue I think. I was working on my Ubuntu 21.10 on my laptop. This laptop is configured with a dual boot with Windows 10. It usually works flawlessly.

I then rebooted it to go on Windows but after the reboot, the USB keyboard and the USB mouse connected to the laptop weren't responding (the Ethernet works well). I then tried to reboot the laptop to go on Ubuntu to investigate the issue but the PC won't reboot! It stays stuck on a black screen. I force it to power off by pressing the button and then restarted the computer to Ubuntu. Still, no USB devices working, I typed lsusb in the terminal and I got an empty output (same result in sudo). dmesg returned me this :

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i usb
[    0.268837] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.268848] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.268853] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.268859] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.593623] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.593646] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.593659] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.103848] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[   11.135109] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: USB bus 1 deregistered
```

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ccm                    20480  3
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_tcc_cooling      16384  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   147456  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
kvm_intel             290816  0
snd_hda_intel          53248  4
iwlmvm                425984  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
kvm                   872448  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec         147456  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
nouveau              2084864  7
mac80211             1024000  1 iwlmvm
snd_hda_core           94208  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
mei_hdcp               24576  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
joydev                 28672  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm               118784  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
aesni_intel           376832  2
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 nouveau
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ttm                    69632  2 drm_ttm_helper,nouveau
rapl                   20480  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
iwlwifi               380928  1 iwlmvm
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
drm_kms_helper        262144  1 nouveau
input_leds             16384  0
processor_thermal_device    20480  0
cec                    53248  1 drm_kms_helper
serio_raw              20480  0
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
snd                    94208  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
cfg80211              892928  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
efi_pstore             16384  0
processor_thermal_rfim    16384  1 processor_thermal_device
rc_core                57344  1 cec
processor_thermal_mbox    16384  1 processor_thermal_device
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
processor_thermal_rapl    20480  1 processor_thermal_device
mei_me                 40960  1
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
intel_rapl_common      24576  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_rapl
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                   131072  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
hid_multitouch         28672  0
intel_pch_thermal      20480  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
ee1004                 20480  0
int3403_thermal        20480  0
int340x_thermal_zone    20480  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
mac_hid                16384  0
int3400_thermal        20480  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
asus_wireless          20480  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             45056  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   561152  9 drm_kms_helper,drm_ttm_helper,ttm,nouveau
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               49152  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_generic            16384  0
mfd_aaeon              16384  0
asus_wmi               40960  2 asus_nb_wmi,mfd_aaeon
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
i2c_hid_acpi           16384  0
r8169                  94208  0
i2c_hid                28672  1 i2c_hid_acpi
i2c_i801               36864  0
intel_lpss_pci         24576  0
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
ahci                   40960  3
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
xhci_pci               20480  0
realtek                32768  1
libahci                36864  1 ahci
idma64                 20480  0
hid                   135168  3 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
wmi                    32768  4 asus_wmi,mfd_aaeon,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  53248  2 asus_wmi,nouveau
```

I looked at the complete dmesg and found these:

```
[    0.364864] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    0.364875] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    1.103837] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.103848] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[   11.134917] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: can't setup: -11
[   11.135109] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: USB bus 1 deregistered
[   11.135510] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: init 0000:00:14.0 fail, -110
[   11.135518] xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:00:14.0 failed with error -110
[   12.829767] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 022554 [ PRIVRING ]
```

```
Linux krusty 5.13.0-22-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 13:21:36 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If you need any more information, I'll add them to this post.

To summary: no USB at all (maybe no power?) and I can't reboot or halt the computer, it stops before on a black screen. I have these problems on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 21.10.

To explain a little better: I can boot to any OSes with no issues at all. When I try to turn off or reboot the computer using the OS, it starts its procedure, and when it is supposed to turn off it gets stuck on a black screen. Same thing during the reboot process. The only solution I found is to press the power button until it powers off and then turn it back on. And my USB ports are not working, it's like they don't even exist.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: You were working in Ubuntu and everything was OK. You rebooted to load Windows and the USB keyboard and mouse stopped working. You rebooted to return to Ubuntu and that OS would not load, or loaded to a black screen. Now you cannot boot into either Windows or Ubuntu and just get a black screen whichever OS you choose. Does that accurately describe the issue? If it doesn't, please review your question and edit it to make it more clear what is happening.

Comment: Sorry english isn't my primary language. I added a part at the end to explain what's happening. Tell me if it is clearer. Thanks!